# Type hinting in Python3.5 : Typed lists with aliases

Tags: python-3.5, type-hinting

sorry for being a newbiem but I don't find any way to solve my problem.

I'm developing a Python application on a 3.5.10 version.

```
    def doStuff(self) -> List[MyClass]:
        variable1 = MyClass()
        myList = list()
        myList.append(variable1)
        return myList
```

I'd like to be able to use an alias as mentionned in [this Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html#type-aliases)

I tried to create aliases for my list but it doesn't work :

```
MyAlias = list[MyClass]
```

I tried to type the code from the documentation as well. It doesn't work neither:

```
Python 3.5.10 (default, Feb 20 2021, 21:50:32)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> Vector = list[float]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

Did I do something bad ?

Answer (score 1):

The older version of Python didn't support this syntax whereas, from Python 3.9, it's available.

```
>>> Vector = list[float]
>>>
```

[PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) introduced this syntax. In older Python versions after 3.5 the syntax as follows

```
>>> import typing
>>> Vector = typing.List[float]
```